# Header Margin Not Specified Anywhere

Tags: html, css, firefox, firebug, stylesheet

I'm having an odd issue.  I have a simple web page, and for some reason the `<h1 />` tag is having a `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of over 18px.  There is nothing in my *.css file that specifies this.  Firefox Firebug shows me the style that is applied, but there is no margin anywhere.

In the picture, the `div` that the header text is in (or supposed to be in) has the limits.  But the header text is pushed down because of the margin.

What could be causing this??  Is there anywhere in firefox/firebug that can show me EXACTLY where that style came from?  It says that the `header` tag inherited from the `body` style, but that is only this:

```
body
{
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: #232323;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Headers often have a margin by default. Have a look at using a reset/normalization stylesheet.

Reset or normalization stylesheets reset your styles to a standard baseline across all browsers. The difference between reset and normalization is that resets clear margins, padding, etc. where normalization stylesheets apply sensible defaults.

These links should be of use:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/is-it-ok-to-use-a-css-reset-stylesheet
- [Reset Reloaded](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/)
- [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/)

Comment: +1 Interesting point of CSS reset stylesheet.  I have never heard of that before.

Comment: The popular resets can be a great starting point. Learn what they have to offer, and you'll probably end up creating your own custom reset (based on your preferences) to use in your projects.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. It's well worth taking the time to understand what they're doing and customise them for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

That's the default styling for `<h1>`s.  It's similar the fact that `<h1>`s have larger text size than paragraphs.  It's just the default.  It can also be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the browsers add some default `margin` and `padding`.

Try resetting the `margin`, like so

```
body{
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: #232323;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin:0;    /*  ADD THIS  */
}
```

You can also reset it on the `h1`

Comment: I reset it in the h1 tag, and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!  +1

Comment: Margins are not inherited, which is why setting the margin on the body won't work.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers have a default CSS that is applied to all pages.

Use something like Yahoo's [Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) to cancel out any styles applied.